# A giant's step - for giants?

Tags: knowledge, geography

Were there giants in Game of Thrones? I didn't watch it - no really, I didn't. No really... Well, to be honest, I did watch the first episode and there were no giants in that.

Anyway, that's enough about me.

If there were giants, you might expect to see them here.

In fact lots of GoT fans do visit here: whether in search of giants or not, I don't know.

Where is *here*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must be

> the [Giant's Causeway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant%27s_Causeway),

which

> sounds (and looks) as though it's for *giants* to *step* on.

It's also

> in Northern Ireland, [where *Game of Thrones* was largely filmed](https://discovernorthernireland.com/things-to-do/attractions/game-of-thrones/game-of-thrones/), so you might expect *Game of Thrones* fans to be around there even if not in search of giants.

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> [Giant's Causeway?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant%27s_Causeway)

It has

> The word giant in it's name. The legend and mythology surrounding it state that the rock formations were created by a giant. Though science says geologic processes are the reason for its notable appearance.

Comment: This is correct up to a point but the final paragraph by @Rand al'Thor nails it completely.

Comment: ninja'd by (exactly) 3 minutes, +1 to you.